# Sorting with command ls in unix (ksh)

Tags: ls, ksh

I'm wondering how does the sort works with `ls`.
For example:

```
ls - lrt tri par date
ls - lSr par size, ...
```

However I don't see how this pattern works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-l` means "long", i.e. it displays long entries, not just filenames. `-r` means reverse the sort order and `-t` means sort by time (file modification time). `-S` is sort by size. So:

```
ls -lrt will sort by time reverse order
ls -lSr will sort by filesize in reverse order
```

for more detail, see `man ls`